# pass form data via jquery post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form and what i need to do is to pass this form data to another page via jquery .post and below you will find the javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("form").submit(function(){
    $(".application_container").append('<div class="preloading" style="padding-top:250px;"><img src="<?php echo base_url() . "assets/images/loading.gif";?>" alt="تحميل" /></div>').show();
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    var url = "<?php echo base_url() . "hawaa/confirm_applicant.html"; ?>";
    $.post(url, function(str){
        $(".application_container").append(str).show();
        $(".preloading").remove();
    });
    return false;
});
   </script>
```

**the error that its request the another page but without sending the form submitted data to it, so it displays the validation error**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `$.post()` incorrectly. You need to pass your data `str` as the data parameter, like so:

```
$.post(url, str, function(data, status, jqXHR) {
    // do stuff with response data here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the `str` variable as the second parameter to the `$.post` call.
The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) states that:

- The first parameter is the URL to which you want to post the data
- The second parameter is the data you want to post
- The third parameter is the results from requesting URL (HTML or XML, depending on what was returned).

So the correct way is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("form").submit(function(){
    $(".application_container").append('<div class="preloading" style="padding-top:250px;"><img src="<?php echo base_url() . "assets/images/loading.gif";?>" alt="تحميل" /></div>').show();
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    var url = "<?php echo base_url() . "hawaa/confirm_applicant.html"; ?>";
    $.post(url, str, function(result){
      $(".application_container").append(result).show();
      $(".preloading").remove();
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>
```